# Simplifying a likelihood function

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I'm trying to simplify following equation:

$\log L(\theta|M)=\sum_{d=1}^D\log\bigg((1-\alpha)(\exp(-\epsilon_b)\frac{\epsilon_b^B}{B!}\exp(-\epsilon_s)\frac{\epsilon_s^S}{S!}+\alpha(1-\delta)(\exp(-(\epsilon_b+\mu))\frac{(\epsilon_b+\mu)^B}{B!}\exp(-\epsilon)\frac{\epsilon_s^S}{S!})+\alpha\delta(\exp(-\epsilon_b)\frac{\epsilon_b^B}{B!}\exp(-(\epsilon_s+\mu))\frac{(\epsilon_s+\mu)^S}{S!})\bigg) $

They have dropped the constant term $−\log(Bd!Sd!)$ and simplified the equation into following factorization:

$\log L(\theta|M)=\sum_{d=1}^D\bigg(-\epsilon_b-\epsilon_s+M_d(\log(x_b)+\log(x_s))+B*\log(\mu+\epsilon_b)+S*log(\mu+\epsilon_s)\bigg)+\sum_{d=1}^D\log\bigg((1-\alpha)x_s^{S-M} x_b^{B-M}+\alpha(1-\delta) \exp(-\mu)x_s^{S-M}x_b^{-M}+\alpha\delta\exp(-\mu) x_b^{B-M}x_s^{-M}\bigg)$

where $M_d=\min(B,S)+\frac{max(B,S)}{2}, x_s=\frac{\epsilon_s}{\epsilon_s+\mu} $  and $x_b=\frac{\epsilon_b}{\epsilon_b+\mu}$.

Unfortunately I do not have a clue how the simplification happened. I would be really thankful and more than happy if somebody could describe the simplification step by step.

If there is anything in addition you need to know, please do not hesitate to ask me.

You can find the whole article which mentions the simplification in the following page:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pinbasic/vignettes/pinbasicVignette.html#general_pin_framework

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE Hasan. I kindly suggest that you type out what's written in the links (in Latex/Mathjax -> just put dollar signs around your expressions!), or otherwise I'm afraid your post will not be received well by the community. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the help Math_QED. Is the question now clear?

Comment: The question is great now. Well done. I voted to reopen it. If everything is all right, you might get an answer soon.